# UI Virtualization Cache Length Change Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone

I am making an app with large set of data, to improve performance I used virtualizing stackpanel inside listbox. Now I have better performance but loading items as they roll in becomes slow when I scroll fast. I am interested:

- what is default number of rendered items? (without those in viewport)
- can I and how to set explicitly number of items to be rendered at the same time?

Currently three items can fit the viewport, I guess that it renders 5-7 items at the time. How can I modify it?